# Python + CPLEX : No module named 'docplex'

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, cplex, docplex

I have the following problem after having installed matplotlib and seaborn :

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-ee0d9503867b>", line 1, in <module>
    from docplex.mp.model import Model

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docplex'
```

my environment has installed docplex and docloud ,but I only use the local version.Conda list output:

[image]

The programs that I install:

1. cplex_studio1210.win-x86-64
2. Anaconda3-2019.10-Windows-x86_64

and my environment :

```
conda create --name PythonOPT1 python=3.7
```

Comment: As an IDE I use spyder and as a operating system  windows 7

Comment: That configuration detail is solved. As the documentation says, create the PYTHONPATH environment variable

Comment: Then present more details. Is the error observed through spyder or skipping spyder and run something from the conda shell? What happens if you run one of the cplex low-level API examples without docplex?

Comment: Do you mean run one of the examples using CPLEX Studio? . There everything works without problem. I think my problem is a matter of module versions.

Comment: What does *there* mean? In the windows-console? The conda-shell? From Spyder? It's hard to read out details here. I would not be surprised to see that this is another *spyder is misconfigured* thing which i observe all the time here (and i see no reason why some *versioning* should be the problem). As a non-spyder user, i don't know what it does with your OS-environment-variables (which seems to be your way of installing cplex; i prefer the other one from the docs).

Answer (score 1):

This error usually occurs when the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable is not set correctly. To debug this add this code before trying to import anything from `docplex`:

```
import os
print('PYTHONPATH="%s"' % os.environ['PYHTHONPATH'])
```

Then double check that the printed value contains the folder that contains the `docplex` and `docloud` installation.

Note that the installation usually sets up the `PYTHONPATH` correctly, but there may be some programs (like certain spyder instances) that may still miss this setting.

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
pip install docplex
```

solved my problem.